# Rendering only partial image using node-webGL, but complete rendering happens in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, webgl

Currently I am using a webGL based browser implementation code at client end. It is working perfectly. But, I am using the same code at server end. Yes, this is not browser based, pure javascript code using node-webgl library. Slight modifications are done, for example replacing new Image() of browser to node-webGL supported format.

I am writing the resulting rendered image into an image file. But the image file shows partial rendering but of same canvas size. Yes with discussion @gman I came to know that browser WebGL and node-webgl are not 100% same implementation, so I am trying to find some alternative functions also to compensate these.

Here is the code;

Entry point:

```
var nodejs=true,
WebGL = require('./node_modules/node-webgl/index'),
document = WebGL.document();
requestAnimationFrame = document.requestAnimationFrame;
alert=console.error;

start1 = new Date().getTime();
//Read and eval library
fs=require('fs');
eval(fs.readFileSync(__dirname+ '/sylvester.js','utf8'));
eval(fs.readFileSync(__dirname+ '/glUtils.js','utf8'));
eval(fs.readFileSync(__dirname+ '/glAux.js','utf8'));
eval(fs.readFileSync(__dirname+ '/volumercserver.js','utf8'));
end1 = new Date().getTime();
console.log(end1-start1);
volumerc_main('/raycast-color.frag','./aorta-high1.jpg','./tfold.png');
```

Excerpt of volumercserver.js (Including complete code)

```
 var Image = require("node-webgl").Image;
 var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

 var Canvas = require('canvas')
 , canvas123 = new Canvas(512, 512)
 , ctx123 = canvas123.getContext('2d');

 var drawVolume;

 var time, end, start;
 var count=0;


/*
main function
*/
function volumerc_main(rayfrag, imgData, imgTF)
{
    start = new Date().getTime();       
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.id = 'canvas_win';
    canvas.width= 512;
    canvas.height= 512;
    var gl;

    try {
        gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", {premultipliedAlpha: false}) || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl",{premultipliedAlpha: false});

    } catch (e) {
    }
    if (!gl) {
        alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
    }   

    gl.shaderProgram_BackCoord = initShaders(gl,'/simple.vert','/simple.frag');
    gl.shaderProgram_RayCast = initShaders(gl,'/raycast.vert',rayfrag, imgData, imgTF);

    gl.fboBackCoord = initFBO(gl, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    initTexture(gl, imgData, imgTF);
    //console.log(gl);
    var cube = cubeBuffer(gl);

    drawVolume = function()
    {

        gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.fboBackCoord);
        gl.shaderProgram = gl.shaderProgram_BackCoord;
        gl.useProgram(gl.shaderProgram);
        gl.clearDepth(-50.0);
        gl.depthFunc(gl.GEQUAL);
        drawCube(gl,cube);

        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
        gl.shaderProgram = gl.shaderProgram_RayCast;
        gl.useProgram(gl.shaderProgram);
        gl.clearDepth(50.0);
        gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);

        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.fboBackCoord.tex);

        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.vol_tex);

        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE2);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.tf_tex);

        gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(gl.shaderProgram, "uBackCoord"), 0);
        gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(gl.shaderProgram, "uVolData"), 1);
        gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(gl.shaderProgram, "uTransferFunction"), 2);

        //Set Texture
        drawCube(gl,cube);


        var pixels = new Uint8Array(canvas.width * canvas.height * 4);
        gl.readPixels(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

         var imageData = ctx123.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
            for (var i = pixels.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {                                  
             {imageData.data[i] = pixels[i]};
             };


            ctx123.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
            console.log(canvas123);

      var fs = require('fs')
  , out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/text.png')
  , stream = canvas123.pngStream();

stream.on('data', function(chunk){
  out.write(chunk);
});

stream.on('end', function(){
 // console.log('saved png');
});                                                 
        end = new Date().getTime();

    }


    setTimeout(drawVolume, 15);         
 }
```

The left partial image is rendered in node-webGL and right is rendered in browser. I do not understand why is there partial rendering in node-webgl. I do not know whether it is limitation of node-webGL or any error in code, how to debug this? (I have not included the complete code of volumercserver.js since it is big).

Is the partial rendering display because of origin being considered at lower left corner in node-webgl(openGL) and origin is considered at top left corner in browser WebGL. how to handle this. If needed I can share the complete code here.

[image]

Comment: have you tried [headless-gl](https://github.com/stackgl/headless-gl) instead? Unliked the poorly named *node-webgl*, *headless-gl* is actually supposed to be real WebGL in node and passes the webgl conformance tests.

Comment: @gman I am currently trying headless-gl, facing with some errors. Like creating of image element using headless-gl(same as new Image() in browser) ?